# Move data from synced Data extension to custom Data extension without duplicates

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I want to move all records from synced data extensions to a new custom Data extension.There are so many duplicated records in synced DE. I want to copy the actual records (without duplicates) to new custom DE.
How can I filter out the duplicates?

Please provide your suggestion..

Thanks in advance

Comment: I fail to understand your issue. There are normally no duplicates in synced DEs, as the record ID is the unique key. You need to be more specific, describing your challenge. What type of object are we talking about? Did you investigate your options with SQL? There are multiple threads here on how to deduplicate records...

Answer (score 2):

If you provide more details about the synched DE structure and what kind of duplicates you have, we will be able to provide a better answer.

For now, I can just offer this generic SQL query for deduplication by email address, which you can run and automate in [Automation Studio](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm&type=5):

```
SELECT contact.Email,
contact.Id
FROM /*synchrinized data extension name*/ contact
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Email,
    MAX(Id) AS Id
    FROM /*synchrinized data extension name*/
    GROUP BY Email
) aggr
ON aggr.Email = contact.Email AND aggr.Id = contact.Id
```

Comment: @JeslinPJ - if this answer helped you, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark - thanks!